# I've written my own npm module, when I import it into a new project, all the asset paths are relative toward the project instead of inside the module?

Tags: javascript, npm

As an example, I have a couple of icons that are used inside the module, however the path '../../public/assets/arrow.svg' works when running the module directly, however when importing it into a project, the module is now trying to find the SVG inside the projects public folder instead. How is this usually handled?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stack overflow. The paths that you are using are relative to your current directory. 
I would recommend you prepend the base directory of your module or something similar to this.